# mysql query array argument

Tags: php, mysql

```
company                    company_to_attributes
=====================      ============================
| id_company | name        id_attributes | id_company
=====================      ============================
| 1          | Test        | 1           | 1             
| 2          | Test 2      | 2           | 1              
| 3          | Test 3      | 3           | 1         
| 4          | Test 4      | 4           | 3
| ..         | ...         | ..          | ... 
=====================      ============================
```

I have a simple array:

```
$array_attributes_IDS = array(1,2);
```

I want write a query for get the companies that have id_attribute from array.

Comment: Please present some examples of what you want to do and what the result should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
$array_attributes_IDS = array(1,2);
$finalArray = implode(',', $array_attributes_IDS);
$arrCount = count($array_attributes_IDS);

$query ="    SELECT com.name
             FROM   company com
             INNER JOIN company_to_attributes att
                ON com.id_company = att.id_company
             WHERE  att.id_attributes IN ($finalArray)
             GROUP  BY com.name
             HAVING COUNT(*) = $arrCount";
```

this will return only one company `TEST` because contains both attributes.

Comment: Thk for the reply. The query works good, but my array is dynimical, i don't how many elements contains. How resolve for the query COUNT ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.* FROM company c INNER JOIN company_to_attributes ca ON c.id_company=ca.id_company WHERE ca.id_attributes IN (1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

please try the following:

```
    $array_attributes_IDS = array(1,2);
    $finalArray = implode(',', $array_attributes_IDS);
    $query = "SELECT C.name FROM company_to_attributes CA INNER JOIN company C ON CA.id_company = C.id_company WHERE CA.id_attributes IN ($finalArray)";
```

Hope this would help.

Comment: Thk for the answer. I would select all companies that have all value of array_attributes_IDS. If have all value.

Comment: @Mike: with INNER JOIN you will get all Companies which are associated with atleast 1 attribute. I hope this is what you want. Or do you want all the comapnies even if it is not associated with any attribute? Please explain

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  c.name
FROM    company c
       JOIN company_to_attributes a
            ON c.id_company = a.id_company
WHERE   a.id_attributes IN (1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "
SELECT t1.name FROM company_to_attributes
LEFT JOIN company AS t1 ON t1.id_company = company_to_attributes.id_company
WHERE company_to_attributes.id_attributes IN (".implode(',', $array_attributes_IDS).")
";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT c.name from company c inner join  company_to_attributes cta ON cta.id_company = c.id_company WHERE   cta.id_attributes IN (1,2);"
```